# PHP server detecting inactivity

Tags: php, server

So I have a PHP server that looks like this

```
<?php 
 $session = $_POST['session'];
 $data = $_POST['data'];
 ... save and process data ...
 echo "got it";
?>
```

And essentially, I will get data about 10 times a second but I want to detect if a session has been inactive for over one minute and make a log record about it. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: This can't easily be done on the server, because PHP scripts don't run unless the client sends a request. If PHP isn't running, it can't check for anything.

Comment: If the saved data contains a timestamp, you can run a cron job on the server that looks for all records whose timestap is older than a minute. That means the corresponding client has been idle.

Answer (score 0):

In every data insert you do, put a timestamp next to it.

E.g. database:

```
1    Sample Data    2018-11-26 00:12:00
2    Sample Data    2018-11-26 00:12:05
3    Sample Data    2018-11-26 00:14:00
```

Now on top of your PHP script, before any incoming insert, get the last row and check the date.

E.g.

```
 $lastRowTime = date_create($row['timstamp']);
 $timeNow = date_create();
 $diff = (date_timestamp_get($timeNow) - date_timestamp_get($lastRowTime)) / 60;

 if ($diff > 1) {
      // it's been 1+ minute since last post, do your logging here...
 }
```